Sending EPS/AI file to Printing company
When sending an eps to a client for printing. Is the a something I should do to the file? For example change the file information, lock the file from editing, etc. Protecting my design, etc?

Usually good idea to outline fonts. But obviously recipient can do this in acrobat pro. No way of protecting your design really. If you dont trust your printer dont use the company. There is no such thing as locking from editing if you can open for viewing you can open for editing.

Most printing companies should be able to print from a PDF directly, so its a bit strange to be asked for source files specifically for printing. Also there is no locking possible, except again with PDF you can lock editing features with a password, but I assume some people know how to get around that, if they wanted to.

Why EPS?  The usual format for print is PDF.  You can export PDFs from illustrator and disable the "Preserve Illustrator Editing Capabilities" option.  You can also make it harder to edit by converting all text to paths. But there is no way to physically stop someone from editing a file if they really want to.  What you want isn't really possible.
